# Force compiler to optimise function in chunks

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

Specifically I am using `gcc -O2 -g`, but it may apply to any compiler.

When I build for optimisation with debug information for profiling, one issue is that the compiler inlines and optimises over the whole function, so from a twenty line function with a few calls, I end up with just four or five line numbers left in the code, and one line number has managed to collect 75% or so of the code, so I find it difficult to tell where exactly is the bottleneck. Let me illustrate:

```
void foo()
{
    // code...
    foo = doThingOne(); // Gets inlined
    bar = doThingTwo(); // Gets inlined

    externalFunction(foo, bar); // Doesn't get inlined
    // code...
}
```

Now, when I look at my profiler output I see something like this - the percentage being the time spent on each post-optimisation line:

```
   void foo()
10%{
       // code...
3%     foo = doThingOne(baz); // Gets inlined
       bar = doThingTwo(wibble); // Gets inlined

75%    externalFunction(foo, bar); // Doesn't get inlined
12%    // code...
   }
```

The 3% might be just something like `push baz`, with the majority of the code lumped into the line for the call of `externalFunction()`. I could of course make `doThingOne()` an external, but that is quite a lot of effort, so it would be nice if I could say something like:

```
void foo()
{
    // code...
    foo = doThingOne(); // Gets inlined
#pragma optimisation_barrier
    bar = doThingTwo(); // Gets inlined

#pragma optimisation_barrier
    externalFunction(foo, bar); // Doesn't get inlined
    // code...
}
```

This would break the optimisation into three chunks, so I could clearly see the relative weights of the three functions in a state close to the actual final running code. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What is `externalFunction`? Is its body visible in the current translation unit?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch no, its body is not visible.

Comment: Then it cannot be inlined, unless you compile and *link* the *entire program* with `-flto -O2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `externalFunction` is declared as external, defined in another translation unit, and not as `static inline` it won't be inlined, unless you ask for **link time optimization** by compiling *and linking* with [`gcc -flto -O2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (e.g. building with `make CC='gcc -flto -O2'`) your *entire* program or library. See also [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html).

GCC has [pragmas for optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html):

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("O2")
```

<sup>(perhaps you might try `#pragma GCC optimize("O3")` *before* your function body)</sup>

> This would break the optimzation into three chunks

But optimization works on bigger pieces, at least on entire function bodies. I believe that thinking in terms of "chunks" to be optimized don't make a lot of sense.

At last, optimization could confuse the profiling information (and the debugging information in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF)). So take it with care, and benchmark the entire program (or at least a full top-level function of your program). I would take with caution the 75% figure.

BTW, [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) does not always mean speed-up (because of [CPU caches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), a bigger code is cache unfriendly). Perhaps you might increase your `-finline-limit=` [setting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). But you could lose performance!

Also, compile your code with `-S -O2 -fverbose-asm` and look into the generated assembler code in `.s` file, you'll then see what has been inlined.